# why AutoComplete toolkit not updated with new items?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, toolkit

I set Datasource of toolkit:AutoCompleteBox to a list of string items. it work good but when I want add a new item to list then set again the list to Datasource of toolkit:AutoCompleteBox , it is not added. 
I think Datasource of toolkit:AutoCompleteBox is not updated.

have you any idea on how to add a new item ? or refresh or update list?

```
List<string> c1 = new List<string>();
//... add some items to c1
txt11.ItemsSource = c1;
c1.Add(txt11.Text.Trim());
txt11.ItemsSource = c1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh my GOD, i found problem easy with this code:
i have to assignment again. first time give null to AutoCompleteBox.

```
List<string> c1 = new List<string>();
//... add some items to c1
txt11.ItemsSource = c1;
c1.Add(txt11.Text.Trim());
txt11.ItemsSource = null; 
txt11.ItemsSource = c1;
```